# Synchronizing time between two Windows 7 machines connected with a LAN cable

Tags: windows, time, p2p, ntp

I have a number laptops that run our application while connected to each other in pairs with an ethernet cable, but not connected to any external network or the internet. T

I need the connected pair to synchronize their system times, but since every computer needs to be able to synch with any other computer, I can't define one computer to be a time-server and the other to be a client.

Is there a way to do this with NTP? Or some other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NET TIME is the way to go. If you do NET TIME \computername /SET it will ask you to confirm if you want to set the time. Just "assign" one of your systems to be the master.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the [Windows Time Service Tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263%28WS.10%29.aspx) with the [manualpeerlist](http://www.petri.co.il/update_the_time_on_windows_xp.htm) options?

See another article here: [How to configure an authoritative time server in Windows Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The Windows Time Service Tools seem to only apply to Windows Server, while we use Windows 7 clients. And the other article describes a client/server hierarchical setup, which is not applicable in my situation.

Comment: @Markus - the tool exists also on Windows Vista/7

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NET TIME](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/120944) command to synchronize time between two computers.

```
net time /?
```

```
The syntax of this command is:

NET TIME

[\\computername | /DOMAIN[:domainname] | /RTSDOMAIN[:domainname]] [/SET]
```

Windows also has a NTP server, just look in Windows Components (or wherever depending on win-version).

Answer (score 0):

You can use special software for synchronization, for example ClockSynchro. Network may be not connected ro internet. Contains ClockSynchroServer and CkockSynchroClient. This program is easy for install and use.
http://clocksynchro.com
On Windows 7 you must run ClockSynchroClient with adminisrtrator permitions ("Run as Administrator")