# Calculate delay of messages between two computers running Java program

Tags: java, delay

I have two programs running on 2 computers (say A and B), both A and B are connected to a private LAN and can ping/send/receive data easily.

I have one method in a program on computer A in which I send a simple string, periodically, to B which receives it.

I set the sending time in the string itself using
`long sent = System.currentTimeMillis()`.

In computer B, I have a thread running to receive the string and process it, upon receiving the string, I get the current time using the same `long receive = System.currentTimeMillis()` and then calculate the final delay using

`long delay = receive - sent; 
 long finalDelay = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`

The issue is that at the receiver side I'm getting weird values, delay in negative (both large and small numbers).

I've tried using `long delay = receive - sent;` without the `TimeUnit` mechanism but still get negative values.

I've synchronized both A and B to a time server. Both are running windows 7 OS, Java 1.7_21 jdk and Netbeans IDE 7.4

I tried using `System.nanoTime()` but it gives the same result and also I think `System.nanoTime()` cannot be used in my scenario as `send` and `receive` will get different start-off time because both run in different JVMs and on different machines.

So the what is the mistake that I'm making? Any help will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE: With the sender and receiver side code**

**Sender**

```
 while (true) {
        try {

            rCon = (RadiogramConnection) Connector.open("radiogram://broadcast:" + HOST_PORT);
            dg = rCon.newDatagram(50);  // only sending 12 bytes of data 
            // Get the current time and sensor reading

            double tempReading = tempSensor.getCelsius();
            long now = VM.getTimeMillis(); // I used System.currentTimeMillis() as well as new Date().gettime() here


            // Flash an LED to indicate a sampling event
            led.setRGB(255, 0, 0);
            led.setOn();
            Utils.sleep(50);
            led.setOff();

            // Package the time and sensor reading into a radio datagram and send it.
            dg.reset();
            dg.writeLong(now);   // I send the time in a datagram
            dg.writeInt((int)tempReading);              
            rCon.send(dg);

            rCon.close();         

            // Go to sleep to conserve battery
            Utils.sleep(SAMPLE_PERIOD - (System.currentTimeMillis() - now));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Caught " + e + " while collecting/sending sensor sample.");
        }
    }
```

**Receiver**

```
public void run()  throws Exception {
    RadiogramConnection rCon;
    Datagram dg;

    try {

        rCon = (RadiogramConnection) Connector.open("radiogram://:" + HOST_PORT);
        dg = rCon.newDatagram(rCon.getMaximumLength());
    } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("setUp caught " + e.getMessage());
         throw e;
    }
    // Main data collection loop
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Read sensor sample received over the radio
            rCon.receive(dg);


            long sendTime = dg.readLong();      // read time of the reading
            int val = dg.readInt();

            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();                

             System.out.println("Original Time : "+sendTime +" ms and Receiving Time : "+time+
                     " ms =:= Temperature value = " + val); 
             System.out.println("The Total delay is: "+(time-sendTime));
```

If I run the sender and receiver on the same computer, then I get expected delay values but on different computers its crazy.

Comment: Show your sending code and receiving code. There is probably a problem on one end.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with the code of both sender and receiver

Comment: I used a utility ClockSynchro mentioned in the last reply [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946221/synchronizing-time-between-two-windows-7-machines-connected-with-a-lan-cable). It synchronizes all computers every 1 minute. I've noticed at the top of minutes the delays are normal but once in a while a negative value appears near the end of minute. It's pretty weird and may be related to hardware but that's all I have now.

Answer (score 2):

Measure the time for a complete round-trip, request and response, at the requesting host, and divide it by two. That way you take any time skew out of the equation.

Comment: While this doesn't really answer his question, I agree, this is what I would do.  Dividing by two is kind of arbitrary since the time on the network is variable anyway.

Comment: @jgitter It's an average of the send and receive times. Averages aren't 'arbitrary'.

Comment: Yes, while agree with your suggestion but I need delay at the receiver side. With this approach the sender will know the delay (one way delay divided by 2) so in order to send that value, I will need to send an extra message to the receiver, which I don't want to do.

Comment: @EJP you don't need to defend your honor... I was just saying you won't know exactly how long it took for the entire message to be sent across the wire since the processing time for the receiver is in there as well.